# Trying to run a pause command on youtube_dl in November 2022

Tags: discord, discord.py

I've made a music bot that plays music but there is one problem, it can't pause/play. I've looked at so many tutorials but all of them seem out of date and don't work any more. Also I've looked through a range of videos actually making the bot but none them work either so I've had to make parts of it with help from a few friends so there may be some other issues. Thanks in advance.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=discord.Intents.all())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{client.user} has connected to discord!")

@client.command()
async def echo(ctx,*, message):
    await ctx.send(f"{message}")
    await ctx.message.delete()

@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
    else:
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {
      'before_options':
      '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
      'options': '-vn'
    }
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': "bestaudio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
      url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
      source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
      vc.play(source)

@client.command
async def pause(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.pause()
    await ctx.send("Paused")

@client.command()
async def resume(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.resume()
    await ctx.send("Resumed")

client.run("My Token Is Here)
```

Comment: Playing music is no longer allowed through Discord bots using YouTube because it violates YouTubes terms of service.

Comment: Is there any other way of playing music??

Comment: Maybe try to look into soundcloud?